# How can I solve Permission denied on deploying app?

Tags: capistrano, digital-ocean

I have setup an app to deploy to my site that is hosted on Digital Ocean CentOS 6 server and I am using Capistrano to deploy the app from my development machine. I have got a repo setup that I push to and that my Capistrano config references when I do `cap development deploy`.

The issue I am having is that it throws this error:

```
[a7406f5e] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/PopupHub/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@repo-url-is-here/popup-hub.git )
DEBUG [a7406f5e]    Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG [a7406f5e]    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

In capfile I have got this:

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'


# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/sitemap_generator'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

In my config/deploy.rb I have:

```
lock '3.1.0'
server "0.0.0.0.0"

set :application, "NameOfApp"
set :scm, "git"
set :repo_url, "git@the-repo-url-is-here/popup-hub.git"
# set :scm_passphrase, ""

# set :user, "deploy"

# files we want symlinking to specific entries in shared.
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# dirs we want symlinking to shared
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake]  = "bundle exec rake" #8
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rails] = "bundle exec rails"

set :branch, ENV["REVISION"] || ENV["BRANCH_NAME"] || "master"


set :keep_releases, 20

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart passenger without service interruption (keep requests in a queue while restarting)'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')

      unless execute :curl, '-s -k --location localhost | grep "Pop" > /dev/null'
        exit 1
      end
    end
  end
  after :finishing, "deploy:cleanup"
  after :finishing, "deploy:sitemap:refresh"
end

after "deploy", "deploy:migrate"
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'

# deploy:sitemap:create   #Create sitemaps without pinging search engines
# deploy:sitemap:refresh  #Create sitemaps and ping search engines
# deploy:sitemap:clean    #Clean up sitemaps in the sitemap path
# start new deploy.rb stuff for the beanstalk repo
```

Then in my config/development.rb I have got:

```
set :stage, :development

set :ssh_options, {
    forward_agent: true,
    password: 'thepassword',
    user: 'deployer',
}

server "0.0.0.0", user: "deployer", roles: %w{web app db}
set :deploy_to, "/home/deployer/development"

set :rails_env, 'development'                  # If the environment differs from the stage name

set :branch, ENV["REVISION"] || ENV["BRANCH_NAME"] || "master"
```

When I push in bash `cap development deploy` the error further up happens.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I have carried out everything fine up to now and I have this setup on another Digital Ocean droplet.

Thanks,

Comment: Have u ssh access using you local system's ssh keys?

Comment: Hi Raj, yeah I can get into the server with ssh but its asks for my password

Comment: you need to upload your ssh keys to remote server http://stackoverflow.com/a/25120188/1047207

Comment: They are uploaded and the permissions changed

Comment: I assume permission error should be gone now... Am I right?

Comment: no its no when I go into the server with ssh and view .ssh/authorized_keys I can see the ssh-key in there and ita correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58622/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-raj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not ssh access to your remote server using you local system's ssh keys.

If you don't have ssh keys on local system, generate:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Upload your local keys to remote server:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@hostname 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Source: [HowToGeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/168147/add-public-ssh-key-to-remote-server-in-a-single-command/)

Comment: RAJ, does this need to be done on the actual server?

Comment: No, on your local system

Answer (score 1):

You need to [set up your SSH key in Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)